# Best way to link specific labels in the test of a webpage to a specific client login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a website  I am developing that will be deployed to several different clients.  All of the functionality is the same and the vast majority of the language used is the same. However, some of the clients are in different industries so specific words and phrases within some pages need to changed based off of the company of the individual logged into the site.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

In the past I have seen people use string database tables but that seems rather cumbersome.  I thought about using localization but I don't want another developer to get confused because it isn't a change in spoken languages.

Comment: I've seen people do this before with Customer Helpers that will display the verbiage differently for clients.

Comment: Some where you need to maintain the industry specific labels , if you don't want to store in DB you can have it in a configfile/resource file having the combination of industry and language and include the label in the view model as property and update it according to the industry chosen. This is the server side approach.

Comment: if you want to do client side approach , have a js file having the specifc labels in json object in it and have some attribute on the element where overriding with specific title needs to be done. have a small javascript code which will look for this attribute and replace the label text with the one that is found in the json object in the other js file or same file

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure if using c# Localization to localize to a specific culture like manufacturing or medical was a correct use of the technology because I wasn't sure how loosely people took the term culture (either meaning a region or a company/corporate industry)

Comment: yes as you said that is not localization and it deviates from the developers understanding also for the application to support multi culture and languages it is better to continue the C# localzation concept and for these items identify the elements that needs change override those separately if they are minimal. if you think you need to support multi language and multi industry specific( combination of them) then better to have it in DB it self ( if you dont want to hit DB server for the same you can have similar stuff in your app_code mdf file and access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use something like a word list. I don't know whether word list is a well know concept or not but let me try to explain it to you.

- You can add the information that distinguishes each login from other based on the companies in one table in your database and map it to corresponding words you wanna use for the respective English or default word in another table.
- Now I am assuming that these words do not change very often. So what you can do is on application start, load it to a convenient memory data structure.
- Now all the text you want to process will go through a word list processor which is basically a program code that identifies the group in which the login is and identifies the words to be replaced. Then it replaces those words based on the appropriate group and returns back the transformed text which you can display in the UI.

So here the advantage is, once the data is loaded into the memory data structure, you don't need to read the values from your DB.

Moreover, if there is any change in the word lists or if you want to give user the handle to change the words according to their preference, you can directly modify the memory data structure and then later refresh it in the DB asynchronously.

Also since the call for mapping is directly from the memory, its faster than DB calls.

And since its a program code, typically a method or something, its totally up to you which text to process and which to ignore.

This is a technique which we used in our application when we had a similar requirement. I hope this suggestion of solution to this problems helps !

Better alternatives and suggestions are always welcome since we would also want to improve our solution to this problem. Thanks.